# BOOST converter layout check

Tags: pcb, boost

He everybody.
I've already done my firts PCB project. I did draw Boost converter and I have a few quenstions about my layout. How is my layout? Can I improve my layout and placement?
If you check and give me some tips I'll be happy.[image: boost_converter]

[image: schematic]

Comment: Please attach a schematic so we can know what components we're looking at.

Comment: @Hans I added schematic sorry.

Answer (score 3):

The basics for all DC/DC converters are:

- Minimize the surface area of high dv/dt nodes (like NetD1_2).
- Minimize inductance or loop area of high di/dt nodes (U2, D1 and C3).

It seems like you have placed them correctly in a small loop.

However I would  consider adding ceramic capacitors on the output (at/near C3). I don't know what switching frequency you're running the 555 timer at, but fast di/dt pulses are likely not caught well by aluminium capacitors. Ceramic capacitors have a much lower impedance at high frequencies (e.g. >100kHz).

I also wonder if you have connected R4-R5-R6 network correctly on your board.

I would consider getting rid of all thermal reliefs on your board. You may want to keep them if you're not confident in soldering with your equipment, but the relief traces are very small which may play up at high currents.

Comment: I agree with your analysis but thermal reliefs might be necessary. They are narrow but also short, if properly sized they won't probably be an issue.

Comment: thank you for worthy analysis. my smps is running at 50kHz I think It doesn't make an ıssue that freq.
Also you are saying I need to minizie my dv/dt and di/dt nodes or you only remind me of general rules.
finally I connected my R4,R5 after smps output , I divided output voltage and I connected 555 by via.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to do a deep analysis of the whole BF487 and see if all the values match, I hope you'll forgive me, but I should be back to work soon.

What I would say is that if you do intend on getting 180V out of this, your clearances on the nets beyond the inductor are *very, very* small as I see them.

Make sure you're up on the guidelines for high voltage and peak transients, or you may at a very low amount of contamination on your board find yourself hearing discharge leak.

Other than that, I do agree with Hans that it's not only smart to add a ceramic on the output, it's needed. Not so much because of some central frequency, but because the sharp switch flanks will be many, many times that dv/dt and your electrolytic will not respond quickly enough to them.

Answer (score 0):

First, I might say it's a reasonable first attempt, track sizes look sensible, and you are on the right track with the large planes in the power handling areas.

Some problems with net GND, C2, for example where it is separated from the rest of the plane by a long, windy narrow section wont be doing much at all. Consider the capacitor, inductor and switch (FET) to form a current loop, which should be made to enclose as small an area as practical. There is a second such loop on the schematic, forming C2, L1, D1, C3.

Tracks running right along the edge are difficult from a manufacturing standpoint, might want to add a keep-out layer around the edges too. The pads attached directly to planes (on D2 for example) are going to be a pain to solder, because the copper plane will draw away the heat.

I notice the use of vias in a few places, and the "blue", which suggests a second layer. If two-sided loading is an option, you could try taking more advantage of the second layer to get a more compact layout. For example, by placing the "power" and "control" circuits on opposite sides, you could make the board take up less than half the current area.